# Existence of vanishing point

Tags: 3d, transformations, projections, perspective

Consider the following example of perspective projection: I have one railway track with two parallel lines meeting at the point $X$ at infinity which is the theoretical approach. This X is called the vanishing point. But practically, this $X$ doesn't exist.

My first question is: How can we say it doesn't exist, but when we see a real image of a railway track, the tracks intersect at $X$?

My second question is: If it exists, how does this $X$ project onto the projection plane during projection? Is it projecting like normal point projection of $(x, y, z)$ onto the view plane $(x_p, y_p, z_p)$?

N. B - I don't want that detailed answer. I just want an intuitive one that is brief and easy to understand.

Comment: The vanishing point that you are talking about exists on the film (i.e. in 2D) and it is defined by the intersection of the projection of said parallel lines. But the vanishing point isn't unique. There are in fact infinitely many vanishing points. You could for example pick slightly rotated boxes (i.e. different angled parallel lines) and each of those would have their own vanishing point(s).

Comment: @joojaa The projections do intersect. It's what artists use when practicing perspective/construction to check that the angles are correct - they continue the projected "parallel" lines, of e.g. their drawn boxes, and check that they intersect at the same vanishing point. The only way the projection of parallel lines do not intersect is if those are parallel to the projection plane/film.

Comment: @lightxbulb l have asked that question, do you have any straightforward answer? So please give the answer without confusing me.

Comment: What part of my answer did you find unsatisfactory?

Comment: @lightbulb, I asked regarding X, what you about X?

Comment: The $X$ that you are talking about exists as a point on the film plane. Artists even draw it to check their construction/perspective. Any point lying on the ray with origin your camera's origin $O$ and direction $X-O$ gets projected to the same vanishing point $X$ on the film plane. That is, all such points can be described through $P(t) = O + t(X-O)$, and if you consider the film plane then $t>1$, if instead you want the film plane to be infinitely close to the camera's origin then $t>0$.

Comment: @User4567: "*I want just intuition which is brief and easy to understand.*" Easy to understand is in the eye of the beholder. The appearance of a thing does not necessitate its existence in the real world. Parallel lines don't intersect; that's what makes them parallel. A projection may cause them to appear to intersect, but they never do in the real world. The projection creates an appearance that does not exist. That's as easy to understand as it gets.

Comment: Even if X exists you can't see it. Why? It's at infinity. Which means even if you built it before the universe existed it's light still wouldn't be here yet. Even if it did the point appears small enough that light from closer points will overwhelm it. Just because you can look at infinity doesn't mean you can see it.

Comment: @candied_orange Please do not conflate an idealized mathematical model with reality. I doubt that helps anyone.

Comment: @lightxbulb please do not conflate an idealized mathematical model with "when we see a real image of a railway track". What you see at X isn't X. You see what approaches X. Call it a pixel, grain of the photograph, or the bars and cones in your eye, whatever X finds itself projected into will be overwhelmed by X's neighbors. There are an infinite number of points that fill X's pixel (or whatever). Of them all, X is not the brightest. So the others dominate the pixel.

Comment: @candied_orange You're not helping anyone by adding unnecessary complexity through the modeling of pixels and so on. It is quite clear that the OP is concerned with a perspective projection - this notion doesn't even require modeling pixels, cameras, apertures or anything of the sort. Since he's mentioning points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ you already know he's referring to a mathematical model and the tracks' example is there to illustrate what the OP seems to be unable to formulate rigorously. Your comment isn't even the main issue. It's painful reading the other handwavy comments here too.

Comment: @lightxbulb Please stop presuming to speak for everyone.

Comment: @candied_orange Go through the other posts of the OP and you'll realize I am not presuming to speak for them. It's the same question asked multiple times in various flavors (also on several different boards) where the tracks are not the crucial part - the OP's confusion about the mathematics and what those mean is the main issue. There's no need to make a simple question more complex by adding speed of light, pixels, the universe, and other considerations - the OP is confused enough as it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131074/discussion-between-candied-orange-and-lightxbulb).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My first question is how we can say it doesn't exist, but when we see real image of railway track they intersects at X?

Because human vision only sees a perspective on reality. It may appear to cause some intersection at a far distant point, but if you change your perspective (by moving towards said far distant point), no such intersection ever actually happens.

Just because you see a thing doesn't make it real.

> My second question is if it exists then during projection how this X is projects in projection plane?

A 2D space cannot capture the entirety of a 3D space. There's too much of it.

As such, any 2D view of a 3D space is going to only present a subsection of it. A perspective projection works by essentially squeezing a triangular prism view of a 3D world into a 2D area. This creates depth distortion, as more distant areas take up less space than areas closer to you.

A "vanishing point" exists after a perspective projection by the nature of the perspective projection.

Comment: Is it projecting like normal point projection (x,y,z) to in view plane (xp,yp,zp)?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "normal point projection". Do you mean a perspective projection? And as has been discussed several times now, it's not a projection if it transforms between spaces that have the same dimensions.

Comment: question is could I represents vanishing point (x,y,z) transforms to (xp,yp,zp)?

Comment: I think there may be a confusion as to what a computer graphics pipeline does versus what projection means

Comment: @joojaa It's much controversial question I have ever seen. Some people saying vanishing point exists some saying it doesn't. Some saying it's projection like normal point. Some saying it represents by projective plane point (X, y, 0) .... Don't know what is right?

Comment: @User4567 It is because people (me included) have trouble understanding what you mean as you have worded it. How do you get $(x_p, y_p, z_p)$ mathematically from $(x,y,z)$?

Comment: @nicol in perspective projection the point (X, y, z) transform to (xp, yp, zp)  , so it should be perspective transformation but why we said it's perspective projection?

Comment: @User4567: "*in perspective projection the point (X, y, z) transform to (xp, yp, zp)*" No, it goes to (xp, yp). There is no Z at the end of the perspective projection process. "*why we said it's perspective projection*" For the same reason we usually say "oak tree" instead of "oak plant", even though both are valid.

Comment: @Nicol I understand at the end (xp, yp) after ndc. But in projection plane it is (xp, yp, zp). Am I correct?

Comment: @Nicol "human vision only sees a perspective on reality."--- could you what does mean by *perspective" here?

Comment: @User4567: It means "[perspective](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/perspective)". Like, from the dictionary.

Comment: @Nicol but one question torturing me. If vanishing point we are seeing is not real. So how can we see it intersects at vanishing point??

Comment: @User4567: Appearance and reality are not the same thing. A mirror does not create a reversed world; it merely reflects light. A lens in front of your retina that bends the path of light does not cause parallel lines to intersect, even if it makes it *appear* as if they do. Objects don't grow in size if they get closer to you, even if the lens over your retinas makes it appear that they do.

Answer (score 2):

In CG the vanishing point can be found computationally by figuring where every pixel on the view plane merges into a single pixel. Imagine a line from every corner of the screen extending out until they touch. That is the vanishing point. It is very literal in computer graphics because no mater what you render beyond that point it will all merge to a single pixel. Now you can move the camera all over the place and that single pixel size block can be anywhere on the screen, it is not unique. But it is still at the vanishing point.

That is the ideal. In practice the vanishing point is much closer because objects become so small that attempting to render them is more or less pointless.

How does it exist in the view plane? If you start with the camera looking at a block covering the entire view plane then start moving backward, that block will become smaller and smaller until it is the size of a single pixel. The camera can keep moving back but what's the point?

Vanishing points in the real world are much more ephemeral as we can get great big telescopes and move them back, we are about to move vanishing points back in the real world even more with the James Web telescope. But in computer graphics the vanishing point is real and can be computed.

Comment: it's not my question answer.. I have asked regarding X? I have demanded about X, it's right?

Comment: My answer is literally taking about the X get a magnifying glass and look at that dot in the middle of the X that is what I am talking about.

Comment: I have demanded projection about X , (X, y, z) to (xp, yp, zp) it's right?

Comment: And that value can be computed, it can be computed in world space, it can be computed in perspective space, and it can be computed in screen space. You can also compute Y and even Z is you want.

Comment: but **joojaa** is saying totally different things, he is saying vanishing point doesn't exist, and it's projection not possible...

Comment: real world vs computer graphics world I think the metaphors are getting mixed here in CG we can also just declare a vanishing point -- edit in CG the world is very limited due to the precision of numbers. This creates limits, the same can be said about drawings on paper or paintings.

Comment: Pwm thats a good answer. Its up to @User4567 to define it for his purposes not for us to define it for him/her.

Comment: At any distance, you can always render things arbitrarily far away from the vanishing point by rendering them arbitrarily far to one side. It's not true that everything far away must render at the vanishing point. If you pick some fixed 2D points (like the corners of the screen)and then adjust the 3rd coordinate you do find a vanishing point.

Answer (score 2):

Vanishing points are a simplified concept that artists use to help them draw perspective images of idealized pinhole cameras. Like so much in art history it's only one possible way to draw 3D imagery. You can use other methods but they are more convoluted and not widely taught to people. Artists have a person in the loop so that person can use judgement so it's the quick and dirty way is good enough.

There is no need to know or even draw a line to a vanishing point to draw a correct perspective image.  You can also use advanced methods to draw fisheye perspectives where straight lines are no longer straight.

- A vanishing point does not exist in 3D space ($R^3$).
- A vanishing point exists in a projection $R^2$.
- But it does exist in a homogenious projective space. But needs to be modelled separately from normal geometry as you can not rely on taking it with you form 3d space. Like normal points

Therefore you can not transform a vanishing point from 3D to 2D which is what you originally asked. But you can create a model where its true.

Mathematically such a point exists at the limit of an infinite line, but there's no set where they overlap. Intersects at infinity is OK. But in practice, there's no difference between a mathematical point and an apparent point. They transform the same way in spaces they exist in.

Now, it is important that we do not regard a 2D image consisting of pixels. We might be rendering vector graphics and thus computing points coordinates not pixels. Yet for practical reasons, an imaging system has to have some minimal width for a line for it to be visible.

Again, as I said earlier, any point sufficiently far away from the camera in 3D is at the mathematically approximate location of a vanishing point in 2D. For all intents and purposes, this is a vanishing point. This point behaves like any other point. But is this in any way useful for your line of query? Probably not since this definition would mean that there are lots of vanishing points in any image, horizon line being all the vanishing points for all lines of a plane.* Your line questioning is sufficiently close to a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to never have a good answer. Consider asking what you want to achieve instead.

Is a vanishing point real? This is a really deep metaphysical question**. In some sense, it's not, if you give me the ability to zoom infinitely then you will never reach it. But you can still identify it and see it. It both does and does not exist at the same time, it's a concept. There is no contradiction here just different models that have different results. The concept exists, after all, it has a Wikipedia page, but so does spider man. Real-world is like that, with lots and lots of conflicting models.***

* If you haven't noticed it, is not very fruitful to ask: "Where is the vanishing point of this image, this camera, or this model?". Because there are probably too many of them. It is however much more fruitful to ask: "Where is the vanishing point of this line?"

** ask a philosophy.se?

*** this reminds me of the fractal nature of the world. If you ask how long is the coastline of a country is you get different answers depending on how accurately you measure. The length of this may be infinite. Which admittedly is not very useful and probably not accepted as real in any pub quiz.

Comment: There's nothing metaphysical about a vanishing point. It's the intersection point of the projection of two lines that are parallel in 3D (whose projection however is not parallel). In homogeneous coordinates the vanishing point in extended 3D (i.e. including infinity) can be represented as $(x_p,y_p,z_p, 0)$. All lines parallel to this direction intersect at this point at infinity.

Comment: @lightxbulb it is not intesect but there is a limit point yes. But even so its a concept that has a solution in some models but not in others.

Comment: Yes, the formal meaning of intersect at infinity (this is valid terminology from projective geometry) implies that they agree in the limit. So all lines parallel to a specific vector $(x,y,z)$ intersect at $(x,y,z,0)$ (one typically makes the vector unit length in order to get a unique representation).

Comment: @lightxbulb yes but like i said this only applies to the homogenious model, it does not follow that there is a point at infinity in normal 3d cartesian space.

Comment: @lightxbulb im not saying that it does not exist in a 2d projection as such but rather i is not a concept that exists everywere. Even here it relies on being able to model infinity somehow in your model

Comment: Yes, that is the point of my comment. The point exists on the projection plane, it doesn't exist in standard 3D space, but it exists in its extension. This doesn't imply philosophy or metaphysics however.That is, if you want to study the 3D vanishing point then you have to consider the projective space.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131034/discussion-between-joojaa-and-lightxbulb).

Answer (score 1):

The vanishing point does not exist in the 3d model, only in the projected image.

> If it exists, how does this X project onto the projection plane during projection?

It's the limit of the projection of the straight rail tracks as distance goes to inifinity,

Comment: could you elaborate more your this statement "It's the limit of the projection of the straight rail tracks as distance goes to inifinity"

Answer (score 1):

> My first question is: How can we say it doesn't exist, but when we see a real image of a railway track, the tracks intersect at X?

You do not see the tracks intersect at X or anywhere else because the tracks do not intersect. However, when they get far enough away and the angles line up, you can no longer distinguish the tracks as two separate entities, and that is what we call the vanishing point. It might be easier to understand vanishing points in the real world before dealing with projections. when you look at a road or a track as it goes around a bend there is a point where the inside of the curve obscures the far side so what is around the bend is no longer visible, but as you approach the corner, you can see further and further around it. That is also known as the vanishing point and it moves as your view point moves.